# How to ignore some class path from gradle scoverage coverage reports?

Tags: gradle, scoverage

how testScoverage task can be configured in Gradle Scoverage to exclude some class from test coverage. In sbt scoverage that can be achieved by adding in settings
coverageExcludedPackages := ";Reverse.*;.*AuthService.*;models\.data\..*
How to achieve same in gradle scoverage

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not described in this plugin [documentation](https://github.com/scoverage/gradle-scoverage), but this plugin exposes a *Gradle extension* named `scoverage` of type [ScoverageExtension](https://github.com/scoverage/gradle-scoverage/blob/master/src/main/groovy/org/scoverage/ScoverageExtension.groovy) that you can use to configure the plugin, see available properties in the [extension source code](https://github.com/scoverage/gradle-scoverage/blob/master/src/main/groovy/org/scoverage/ScoverageExtension.groovy).

You could configure excluded packages as follow, for example:

```
scoverage{
    excludedPackages = ["Reverse.*",".AuthService." , "models.data"]
      // TODO : configure patterns correctly, this is only a dummy example
}
```

Note: I did not test this plugin myself, but looking at the source code, this is how it's supposed to work.